# What are differences between .NET SDKs for Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, sdk

I have found two similar .NET libraries for Azure:

- [azure-libraries-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net)
- [Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net)

What is the difference? What is the intended use of them? Which one should I prefer for .NET/C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [azure-libraries-for-net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#azure-management-libraries-for-net) is a management library, for managing Azure resources. 
Previously, it's a part of [Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net#azure-sdk-for-net) in `Fluent branch`. Since Sep 23, 2017, the Fluent branch is moved to `azure-libraries-for-net`, you can see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent) for moved information.

> For what's the difference:

azure-libraries-for-net is called `Fluent sdk`(all the packages have a postfix `.Fluent`, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#latest-stable-release)), the code is easier to read and write. For example, if you want to create a virtual machine, you can just use one statement to create a virtual machine. Please refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simpler-azure-management-libraries-for-net/) for usage of fluent sdk.

[Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net#azure-sdk-for-net) is called `Generated SDK`, and is not only for management, but also for the detailed operation, like [upload a file to blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample01a_HelloWorld.cs#L24).

Here is an [article](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/06/working-with-azure-management-rest-apis.aspx) which compares the `Fluent sdk` and `Generated sdk` for azure, it explains them very well.

> Regarding Which one should I prefer for .NET/C#:

It depends on you. When using Fluent sdk, the code is easier to read and write. But sometimes, if the feature is not implemented / or in preview in Fluent sdk, you should choose Generated SDK.